# Unable to connect to SMP 2.3 via Relay Server - iOS App

Tags: ios, ios7, sup, sap-smp

I am getting Error code 516 while synchronizing data in iOS app from SMP 2.3. The device gets registered and then the app does not move forward to home screen. The log file shows following error in Xcode :

> SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED, code = 516, message = Error: 516 Detail: Error sending request to server Native Error: -2 Source: moClient.cpp 1907.

This error comes when the app is unable to connect to the server. However, I have tried almost every combination of configuration but the app is not working. Another app with the same configuration works but when I am trying to replicate the same configuration with new app, it throws the above error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You say the device gets registered correctly but the synchronisation fails. This is usually due to a misconfoguration of the synchronisation profile. Are you setting the correct stream paramters? Farm ID checked?